# Get a data from app-root to component

Tags: angular

```
<body>
  <app-root data="myData"></app-root>
</body>
```

I need to retrieve `myData` that I will manually add at `index.html` and use it into a component.

How can I retrieve this data?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are manually adding it, why not just manually add it into the component in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify @Input() parameter for Angular root component/module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543928/specify-input-parameter-for-angular-root-component-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this answer has what you need:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43544999/3581932

Use @Attribute (for Angular 4)

**index.html :**

```
<my-app myAttribute="myAttributeValue">
    <div>Loading...</div>
</my-app>
```

**app.component.ts :**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
        let myAttribute = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('myAttribute');
    }
}
```

[Copied directly from above post]